# Examples on how to give a proof or a counterexample of a statement

Tags: proof-writing

Examples; Prove or give a counterexample of the following statements,with quantifiers:

1) For each non-negative number s, there exists a non-negative number t such that s≥t

2) For each non-negative number t, there exists a non-negative number s such that s≥t

How could i proceed?

Comment: This holds if only if s<=t  and t<=s!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(\forall s\geq 0)(\exists t\geq 0)(s\geq t\land (\forall t\geq 0)(\exists s\geq 0)(s\geq t))\to (s=t)
$$

Comment: @Jyanluka You should ask that as a separate question. :)

Comment: Oops sorry for the mistake!